# Pandas: How to alter entry in current row dependant on selection of all rows up to current row

Tags: pandas

Trying to learn pandas using English football scores.

Here is part of a list of football matches in date order.
"FTR" is the Full Time Result: "A" - win for the away team, "H" - win for the home team, "D"- a draw.

I created columns "HTWTD" - home team wins to date, and "ATWTD" - away team wins to date, to hold the number of wins the home and away teams have had up until that point. I populated the columns with 0s then put a 1 in the HTWTD when the FTR was H, and  a 1 in the ATWTD where the FTR was A. This obviously only produces correct data for the first time each team plays.

When we get to row 9, Leeds wins a match having already won one in row 2. The HTWTD in row 9 should read 2 i.e at this point Leeds has won 2 games.

To my untrained mind the process should be...

Look at the row above, if Leeds features, get the corresponding HTWTD or ATWTD score, add 1 to it and put it in the current row HTWTD or ATWTD column. If Leeds doesn't feature (and you are not at the first row) go up one row.

Having googled around I haven't found anything about how to select only rows above current row, then alter entry in current row depending on test on selected rows.

I could probably write a little python function to do this, but is there a pandas way to go about it?

| Row | Date | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | FTR | HTWTD | ATWTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12/09/2020 | Fulham | Arsenal | A | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 12/09/2020 | Crystal Palace | Southampton | H | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 12/09/2020 | Liverpool | Leeds | H | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 12/09/2020 | West Ham | Newcastle | A | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 13/09/2020 | West Brom | Leicester | A | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 13/09/2020 | Tottenham | Everton | A | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 14/09/2020 | Brighton | Chelsea | A | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 14/09/2020 | Sheffield United | Wolves | A | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 19/09/2020 | Everton | West Brom | H | 1 | 0 |
| 9 | 19/09/2020 | Leeds | Fulham | H | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `.eq()` to return a boolean series of True or False for the condition and then use `.cumsum()` to cumulatively get the sum of the `True` values per `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` group result with a `.groupby`:

```
df['home_wins'] = df['FTR'].eq('H')
df['away_wins'] = df['FTR'].eq('A')
df['HTWTD'] = df.groupby('HomeTeam')['home_wins'].cumsum()
df['ATWTD'] = df.groupby('AwayTeam')['away_wins'].cumsum()
df.drop(['home_wins', 'away_wins'], axis=1)
Out[1]: 
   Row        Date          HomeTeam     AwayTeam FTR  HTWTD  ATWTD
0    0  12/09/2020            Fulham      Arsenal   A      0      1
1    1  12/09/2020    Crystal Palace  Southampton   H      1      0
2    2  12/09/2020         Liverpool        Leeds   H      1      0
3    3  12/09/2020          West Ham    Newcastle   A      0      1
4    4  13/09/2020         West Brom    Leicester   A      0      1
5    5  13/09/2020         Tottenham      Everton   A      0      1
6    6  14/09/2020          Brighton      Chelsea   A      0      1
7    7  14/09/2020  Sheffield United       Wolves   A      0      1
8    8  19/09/2020           Everton    West Brom   H      1      0
9    9  19/09/2020             Leeds       Fulham   H      1      0
```